# How does this assignment of an object to a variable really works?

Tags: javascript, object, variables, variable-assignment

Consider the following code

```
let foo = 'test'
const obj = {foo}
```

If we `console.log(foo)` we can see that obj is an object `{foo : 'test'}`

How does that work?

I mean, I would expect `const obj={foo}` to be evaluated into `const obj = {'test'}` which will throw a syntax error.

So why variable `foo` inside curly braces in the right part of an assignment becomes `foo: "valueof" foo` instead of being just the value of foo?

Comment: `const obj = {foo}` is just a shortcut for expression `const obj = {foo: foo}`

Comment: If you want to use the value of `foo` as key you can do `{[foo]: 'someValue'}`